# Container-Fluid Vertical divisions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a general question about Bootstraps container-fluid and vertical divisions. I've read many of the posts out there but I can't seem to find a solution to this particular issue.

I have a container-fluid that divides by 12 horizontally but I want it to divide by 12 vertically to. This is because I want to keep the aspect ratio the same.

- Basically is there a way I can say something like... ''
- I would like to control the aspect ratio for text containers as well as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I would do it

you must set the 'height' property from the root element to the deeper, for this effect to work.

**CSS**

```
html, body,
.full-height {
    height: 100%;
}
.row-md-1 {
   height: 8.3%;
   max-height: 8.3%;
}
.row-md-1:last-child {
   height: 8.4%;
}
.cell {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;   
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container-fulid full-height">
    <div class="row row-md-1">
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
       <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 cell"></div>
   </div>
    ...  11 rows later
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**SAMPLE**

http://www.bootply.com/0OJVOy28BD#

In the above example, use a height of 100%, but you can change this to have the same height as width with a little javascript. I do not know a pure form using css.

Complete example:

http://www.bootply.com/8JyjPpKyxm